# bootstrap - location of submenu per type of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a doubt. I am designing my website  using bootstrap with main horizontal nav at the top. Lets assume I clicked on a link that shows list of games.  Also, there will be another link that shows list of movies.

So, whenever I click something related to games, I want to show another nav that shows links only related to games, like:

```
list of games
vote a game
reviews for a game
blah blah blah for a game
```

And, whenever I click something related to movies, I want to show another nav(apart from main top nav) that shows links related to movies only.

So, considering bootstrap horizontal top nav, where should I keep this subnav ? Not getting any good place to keep that nav.

Can you please suggest some links or your own suggestion.

Comment: Are you talking about a drop down for each category on your nav?

Comment: No, all those come  under common top nav. But, in a normal desgign, we usually have a single horizontal nav, split by a horizontal line, upper part of horizontal line shows common links and links below the line show links particular to that page or they are related to the link(that is above line) clicked.  But in bootstrap, that is  not possible. wat my problem is, if I keep another horizontal nav particular to that page some gap below the main nav wont look good. so some example links wud help me.